# Create page with data in a list SharePoint 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I have a news list in SharePoint 365, when i save an item on a list, i execute a JavaScript code that creates a page with a title.aspx. I need that the page titulo.aspx get the parameters (foto, detalle), and show in the page title.aspx.

I have used the below code:

```
function QuerySuccess() {
//Create Publishing Page using PublishingPageInformation object 
var titulo= document.getElementsByName("ctl00$ctl41$g_546a6056_4673_4aa0‌​_885c_f7d207b9cbe4$f‌​f11$ctl00$ctl00$Text‌​Field")[0].value; 
console.log(titulo.concat(".aspx")); 
var newPublishingPage = SP.Publishing.PublishingWeb.getPublishingWeb(clientContext, oWeb);
var pageInfo = new SP.Publishing.PublishingPageInformation(); 
pageInfo.set_name(titulo.concat(".aspx"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code in your success method

```
function QuerySuccess() {  
    var newPublishingPage = SP.Publishing.PublishingWeb.getPublishingWeb(clientContext, oWeb);  
    var pageInfo = new SP.Publishing.PublishingPageInformation();  
    pageInfo.set_name("Test Page.aspx");  
    pageInfo.set_pageLayoutListItem(pageLayoutitem);  
    newPage = newPublishingPage.addPublishingPage(pageInfo);  
    clientContext.load(newPage);  
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(SecondQuerySuccess, SecondQueryFailure);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information Venkat I create the page corectly , but i need a create a page with content (foto,detalle), not a blank page. The code works good.

Comment: @AlvaroLópezGaete did you find a solution?